# PDP page gets redirected to 404 for some products

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-storefront

I need some help with this issue in Vue Storefront that I have had some difficulty trying to solve:

After navigating to PDP(Product Detail Page) and refreshing the page, the page gets redirected to ‘page-not-found’ for many products. The products that get redirected to page-not-found are always the same and not all products get redirected to page-not-found. Traversing to the PDP using router-link works, even when the path is hardcoded, but navigating directly to it or refreshing the page while on a PDP doesn’t work. I also tried isolating the problem and found that even including just the Product.js mixin file from the core and removing all other code on PDP still causes the redirect.

I am unable to solve this bug despite trying for days. Even if you can’t see what is causing the issue, it would be helpful if anyone can at least show me how to debug this issue. I don’t know how to know what code is causing the redirect to 404.

Thanks

Comment: Could you share some isolated code?

Comment: @Alizadeh118 I think it would be difficult to give any particular code as I don't know what is causing the bug. Could you be able to help me in some other way, such as is there a way to debug the route transitions so that I can figure out where the redirect is happening? Thanks for the prompt replay.

Answer (score 0):

Is behavior  present only for given type of products (like bundle) or do they have some common characteristic?

The problem may be lack of some data during SSR refresh. Then on a client side product can't be fetched. This can happen if we are missing some checks for some specific product types. Can you ping me on VS slack and give access to the code? Looks like the fault is on our side :)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of VS are You using? If 1.9 - please make sure You've got the products properly imported with the `product.url_path` set. Then please do check if You don't have